# Spatialite Android (Transform and Distance)

Tags: android, spatialite

I am working with SpatiaLite for Android from [Gaia-SINS](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/) using [this tutorial](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=spatialite-android-tutorial).

I managed to create spatial database and it works fine. But I have problem getting distance between points (or any other geometry) in meters.

I was searching the web, and found many examples that uses `Transform` to get distance in meters. Projection that I use is 4326 and I insert points as `POINT(Lon Lat)`. To calculate the distance I transform it to projection with SRID 3035.

The problem is that when I use transform on Android it returns NULL. I Compared it with [SpatiaLite_GUI](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/index), in it this query works fine.

Can anyone say me why `Transform` on phone is not working? Is it because of the projection 3035 or something else?

**[EDIT]**

Here is simple SQL that is working in SpatiaLite GUI and not on Android.

```
SELECT Distance(
    Transform(GeomFromText('POINT(21.865466 43.327717)', 4326), 3035),
    Transform(GeomFromText('POINT(21.895659 43.32116)', 4326), 3035)) as Distance;
```

This query returns 2550.215591 in SpatiaLite GUI and 0.0 in Android. The 2.5km is correct distance.

The same query without `Transform` returns 0.030897 in both SpatiaLite GUI and Android.

```
SELECT Distance(
    GeomFromText('POINT(21.865466 43.327717)', 4326),
    GeomFromText('POINT(21.895659 43.32116)', 4326)) as Distance;
```

Comment: Why do you need Android code when this is SQL ?

Comment: You are right. It was problem with android code. I forgot to post the answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question.

The problem was in creating database. I am creating it in code and i haven't added `spatialite_create()` to create spatialite meta data in database.

```
Database db = new Database();
db.open(Constants.SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | Constants.SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE);
db.spatialite_create();
```